# Execute local script on remote without copying it across in Ansible

Tags: ansible

Is it possible to execute a local script on a remote host in Ansible without copying it across and then executing it?

The script, shell and command modules all seems like they might be the answer but I'm not sure which is best.

The script module describes itself as "Runs a local script on a remote node after transferring it" but the examples given don't suggest a copy operation - e.g. no src, dest - so maybe this is the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

script module FTW

tasks:

```
- name: Ensure docker repo is added
  script: "{{ role_path }}/files/add-docker-repo.sh"
  register: dockeraddrepo
  notify: Done dockeraddrepo
  when: ansible_local.dockeraddrepo | d(0) == 0
```

handlers:

```
- name: Done dockeraddrepo
  copy:
    content: '{{ dockeraddrepo }}'
    dest: /etc/ansible/facts.d/dockeraddrepo.fact
```

Comment: An explanation of the provided code would be very helpful to others.

Comment: Is there any way to run the local script on remote nodes as an ad-hoc command?

Comment: i guess you mean, can you run execute a command on remote machines instead of a local script ... am sure there is a module for that .. the command module maybe? been a while since i used ansible